# How to seperate displacements for different parts of the object?

Tags: node-editor

I want to have voronoi displacement only on one checkers, others should remain without application of this texture. How to make this 'mask' seperation. Adding picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're close!** But I think this is more what you're after.

[image: Screenshot.]

Essentially you've got to think of the `Checker Texture` node as being a 'master-mask' which is used as the `Fac` input when mixing the other textures together. The black part of the checker will be the top input of the `MixRGB node`, and the white will be the bottom.

When working with the `Displacement` node, middle-grey (a value of `0.5`) will be no-displacement. This means that you can add the `Voronoi Texture` to either the top or bottom inputs of the `MixRGB` node, and as long as you set the other input color to be the middle-grey, and add the `Checker Texture` mask to the `Fac` input, then the Voronoi texture will only affect either the white, or black, sections of the mask.

---

[image: Comparison Screenshot]

^ Here's a screenshot comparing the difference between applying the `Voronoi Texture` to the bottom and top inputs of the displacement's `MixRGB` shader, while using the `Checker Texture` as the `Fac` input.

**Hope that helps!**